Building GCC 12.2.0 from source for aarch64 target
I've been trying to cross compile the source code to build GCC 12.2.0 for my RaspberryPi 4 B running Ubuntu 22.04. SO far I've tried doing this while configuring the project:
../gcc-12.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix-path=/opt/cross/gcc-12.2.0/build_aarch64 --disable-multilib

But this does not work, as when I'm building the project using make, the bootstrapping phase gives me a bunch of errors related to zstd.
undefined reference to `ZSTD_getErrorName'
undefined reference to `ZSTD_isError'
undefined reference to `ZSTD_compress'
undefined reference to `ZSTD_getErrorName'
... (you get it)

How do I go about solving this? Am I doing something wrong configuring my project? I've been looking at this from just straight up searching my error: https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1613, but it seems like scuffing it a bit, right?
Would appreciate your help, guys.

Is there a particular reason you’re trying to compile this yourself, rather than use the g++-12-aarch64-linux-gnu cross-compiler package?

That's based on GCC 12.3.0, right? I'm looking for something that's specifically GCC 12.2.0.

What is different in this snippet compared to e.g. Musl-LFS are the different parameters for --build and --host, which in Musl-LFS are equal, and the lack of --target. The original LFS has only --target in the first step, and --host equal to --target in the second step

Also, are you sure the aarch64-linux-gnu is the correct triplet? LFS contains a section on "system triplets", which should actually consist of four parts.

@Vilinkameni the triplet is fine, but your point about the arguments is a good one — it all depends on whether the goal is to cross-compile a native ARM64 compiler, or compile an x86-to-ARM64 cross-compiler.

Yup @StephenKitt, the goal is compile a native ARM64 compiler. That's why I have specified my host (which as per the documentation is the machine on which the resulting compiler is supposed to run) to be aarch64-linux-gnu.

@Vilinkameni, the --host and --target default to be the same thing, that's why no target is specified (as intended).

Yes, but cross compilers are usually built in several stages. LFS and Musl-LFS both use three stages. In Musl-LFS, in the first two stages,  --build == --host != --target, and only in Musl-LFS stage 3 is --build != --host == --target. In LFS stage 1, --build and --host are not specified, only --target is. In LFS stage 2, --build is set to the value returned by config.guess, and --host == --target. LFS stage 3 runs in chroot and doesn't specify any of --build, --host and --target.

Usually stage 1 is built as minimal as possible, only to enable the compilation of libc and few select utilities and libraries for the following stage. Stage 3 is the fully-featured final version, built using the libraries and utilities from the final target system.

Since you’re trying to cross-compile a native ARM64 compiler, you need to install the required libraries and development files for ARM64. On Ubuntu, the easiest way to do this is to enable arm64:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
sudo apt update

Then you’ll be able to install libraries using :arm64:
sudo apt install libzstd-dev:arm64

You’ll need to repeat that with any other library needed to build GCC.

Great idea. Let me try.

Now I'm getting some Assembler errors, no such architecture armv8, ... Which library should I install here?
